# Get properties of object in its function when it called by HTMLElement.onclick event - javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, this, prototype

I have a several HTML elements I wanted to handle `onclick` for. In javascript code I defined the prototype that have property `name` and function `whoAreYou()` that must be `onclick` handler. It looks like:

```
var Somebody = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Somebody.prototype.whoAreYou = function() {
    console.log("I am " + this.name)
};

var somebody = new Somebody("Gary");
document.getElementById("somebody1").onclick = somebody.whoAreYou;
```

But `this` is refered to HTML element but not to `somebody` and instead of "I am Gary" it says "I am undefined".

It was working while `whoAreYou` was defined inside of constructor but I need inheritability. How can I access his `name` considering `whoAreYou` is moved to `Somebody.prototype`?

Comment: That’s because the `this` in event handlers is the element that was interacted with.  You can change the `this` using bind but then you have no reference to the clicked element, which might be ok and might not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the context:

```
document.getElementById("somebody1").onclick = somebody.whoAreYou.bind(somebody);
```

or

```
document.getElementById("somebody1").onclick = function() { 
  somebody.whoAreYou()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the `whoAreYou` function on click:

```js
var Somebody = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Somebody.prototype.whoAreYou = function() {
    console.log("I am " + this.name)
};

var somebody = new Somebody("Gary");
document.getElementById("somebody1").onclick = function() {
    somebody.whoAreYou();
};
```

```html
<div id="somebody1">click me</div>
```